# Count data from two columns in one or two queries

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2005, count, distinct

I have the following distinct rows in my table:

```
JobID   ClientID    Date                URL
a       1           Apr 27 2020 8:21AM  http://somewebsite.com
a       1           Apr 29 2020 12:57AM http://somewebsite.com
a       1           Apr 30 2020 5:05AM  http://anotherwebsite.com
a       2           May 3 2020 6:09PM   http://anotherwebsite.com
a       3           May 20 2020 12:55AM https://thirdlink.com
b       1           Apr 30 2020 5:16AM  http://anotherwebsite.com
b       2           May 3 2020 6:09PM   http://anotherwebsite.com
b       2           May 11 2020 8:39AM  https://thirdlink.com
```

I am trying to builder either one or two queries that would give the following results:

- Aggregated number of clicks per Client per Job:

```
JobID   ClientID    Number of Clicks
a       1           3
a       2           1
a       3           1
b       1           1
b       2           2
```

- Number of unique URLs per Client per Job:

```
JobID   ClientID    Number of URLs
a       1           2
a       2           1
a       3           1
b       1           1
b       2           2
```

This is what I have tried but it does not aggregate the data correctly:

```
SELECT ClientID,
COUNT(ClientID) AS [Number of Clicks],
JobId
FROM [table]
GROUP BY ClientID, JobId
```

```
SELECT ClientID,
COUNT(URL) AS [Number of URLs],
JobId
FROM [table]
GROUP BY ClientID, JobId
```

Any tips on how to achieve this would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, it’s sql server, I mixed up the tag

Comment: Your 1st query is correct although you can replace `COUNT(ClientID)` with `COUNT(*)`. In your 2nd query use `COUNT(DISTINCT URL)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cause aggregation and `count()` as follows:

```
select 
    jobid, 
    clientid, 
    count(*) cnt_clicks, 
    count(distinct url) cnt_distinct_url
from mytable
group by clientid, jobid
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: `Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '' to data type bit.`